# How to get the data in a DataGridView into an EPPlus ExcelWorksheet

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, epplus

I've tried this code which throws a cast exception:

```
Dim worksheet As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(pageTitle)
Dim dataTable As DataTable
dataTable = dataGridView.DataSource ' cast exception
```

Exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable'.

I need a `DataTable` to set the worksheet:

```
worksheet.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, True)
```

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. The `DataSource` property of a `DataGridView` can be one of various types, one possible type is `DataTable` and another is `BindingSource`. Yours is presumable a `BindingSource`.

Comment: Yes, the `DataSource` is `BindingSource`. I need a `DataTable` to set the data in the worksheet. (I've added to question).

Comment: Interesting that `dataTable` is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable` instead of `System.Data.DataTable` - I don't think you need to reference the interop assemblies with EPPlus, but you need to fix that declaration.  Also, is the `BindingSource` using a `DataTable`, `DataSet` or something else as it's `DataSource`?  It may be as simple as `Dim dataTable As System.Data.DataTable = DirectCast(DirectCast(dataGridView.DataSource, BindingSource).DataSource, System.Data.DataTable)`, but I don't think you have given us enough information to know for sure.

Comment: How is the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView` being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot convert the `DataSource` to a `DataTable` directly, you can extract the visible data in the `DataGridView` to a new `DataTable` using the following routine:

```
  Public Function Dgv2Dtb(ByVal dgv As DataGridView) As DataTable
    Dim dtbOutput As New DataTable
    For intCol As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
      Dim dgvc As DataGridViewColumn = dgv.Columns(intCol)
      Dim dtyCol As System.Type = dgvc.ValueType
      If dtyCol Is Nothing And dgvc.CellType.Name = "DataGridViewTextBoxCell" Then
        dtyCol = GetType(String)
      End If
      Dim dclOutput As DataColumn = New DataColumn(dgvc.HeaderText, dtyCol)
      dtbOutput.Columns.Add(dclOutput)
    Next intCol
    For intRow As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
      Dim drwNew As DataRow = dtbOutput.NewRow()
      Dim dgvr As DataGridViewRow = dgv.Rows(intRow)
      For intCol As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
        drwNew.Item(intCol) = dgvr.Cells(intCol).Value
      Next intCol
      dtbOutput.Rows.Add(drwNew)
    Next intRow
    Return dtbOutput
  End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim dtbNew As DataTable = Dgv2Dtb(dgvMyDataGridView)
```